# c++ : Defining array within an if-else condition erases after it exits

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, memory-management

I have a script that fills in an array, either by using a function, or not.

It takes in an argument `readmode`, it decides whether to use the function or not; and an argument `len_arr`, which decides the length of the array.

I simplified the code so that every iteration the array length increases every iteration, but in actual situation, every iteration i load audio files so that are of different length, hence i use malloc to init, an then i free it once i am done post-processing it.

Main Script

```cpp
// imports
  #include <iostream>     /* cout */
  #include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
  #include <stdlib.h>     /* atoi */
  using namespace std;

  void function_1(int len_arr, double * output_buffer){
    for (int j=0; j<len_arr; ++j){
      output_buffer[j] = 1.0*j;
    }
  }


int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
  int readmode = atoi(argv[1]);

  // double *buffer;
  // cout << "1 : Memory Address of buffer="<<buffer << endl;

  for (int len_arr=1; len_arr<=5; ++len_arr){

    if (readmode==1){
      double *buffer = (double *)malloc(len_arr * sizeof(double));
      function_1(len_arr, (double*)buffer);
      cout << "\n2 : Memory Address of buffer="<<buffer << endl;
      printf("readmode=1 : buffer[:5]=[%f %f %f %f %f]\n", buffer[0],buffer[1],buffer[2],buffer[3],buffer[4]);

    } else if (readmode==2){
      double *buffer = (double *)malloc(len_arr * sizeof(double));
      for (int j=0; j<len_arr; ++j){
        buffer[j] = 1.0*j;
      }
      cout << "\n3 : Memory Address of buffer="<<buffer << endl;
      printf("readmode=2 : buffer[:5]=[%f %f %f %f %f]\n", buffer[0],buffer[1],buffer[2],buffer[3],buffer[4]);
      
    }

  /* Do my post-processing with buffer */

  // verbose
    cout << "\n4 : Memory Address of buffer="<<buffer << endl;
    printf("readmode=%i : buffer[:5]=[%f %f %f %f %f]\n", readmode, buffer[0],buffer[1],buffer[2],buffer[3],buffer[4]);
    free(buffer);

  }
  return 0 ;
}
```

I compiled it like this

```sh
g++ -o ./debug_ifelse.out -Ofast -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 "./debug_ifelse.cpp"
```

> **Here are the problems i faced:**

1. If i dont initialise `double *buffer` prior to entering the if-else, i get compilation error that it was not declared, even though i did define it within each of the condition.

```sh
./debug_ifelse.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
./debug_ifelse.cpp:41:48: error: ‘buffer’ was not declared in this scope
     cout << "\n4 : Memory Address of buffer="<<buffer << endl;
                                                ^
./debug_ifelse.cpp: At global scope:
./debug_ifelse.cpp:14:15: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
               ^
```

2. When i do initialise it (though i dont see the meaning to), the variable `double *buffer` outside and within the if-else seems to be in different memory address, and i cant access the one that was defined within the if-else.

```sh
1 : Memory Address of buffer=0

2 : Memory Address of buffer=0x24f3030
readmode=1 : buffer[:5]=[0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000]

4 : Memory Address of buffer=0
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: I dont think the code you pasted here will compile.

Comment: Tip: in C++ use `std::vector` and stay away from C arrays and pointers whenever you can. You can just use `push_back` instead of all of this reallocation code.

Comment: @tadman The reason i am using arrays is because i read buffer as an audio file, as mentioned in paragraph 3 of my question, using `sf_read_double (infile, buffer);` which loads the audio to array. I simplified the reading to an audio file as simply filling it with `function_1`. But the main purpose of the question is to tackle why after i exit the if-else condition, my buffer cannot be used.

Comment: You're declaring things inside the `if` scope, so it's not accessible outside of that. You'll need to declare the pointer prior to the branching code.

Comment: You ca also create a vector of whatever size you want and use it like a buffer, writing to it as if it's just a pointer, which simplifies memory management dramatically.

Comment: @tadman well, [sf_read_double](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/api.html#read) uses array in double by default, which limits the changing of data structure on my part..

Comment: `std::vector<double> buffer`, `push_back()` as necessary, and then use [`data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) to access the low-level data. Easy. This doesn't change the data structure, it changes how it's allocated and managed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uncomment this // double *buffer;  buffer should be defined above for loop.

```
double *buffer;
```

in if-else blocks just use buffer without defining it.

```
buffer = (double *)malloc(len_arr * sizeof(double));
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the error:

```
./debug_ifelse.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
./debug_ifelse.cpp:41:48: error: ‘buffer’ was not declared in this scope
     cout << "\n4 : Memory Address of buffer="<<buffer << endl;
```

Look at line 41 - you use variable `buffer` so if it is commented out in line 40 then it isn't declared in scope - like the error says.

Note that if you do declare it on line 40, then this line.

```
double *buffer = (double *)malloc(len_arr * sizeof(double));
```

Creates another (different) variable of the same name which is probably not want you want. Make it `buffer = (double *)malloc(len_arr * sizeof(double));`

Note you do need `buffer` on line 40 because after all your loops you `free(buffer)`, so it is needed in that scope.

Side notes:

- Because your loop keeps saying `buffer = malloc(...` you are leaking
  memory
- If you are in C++ why malloc/free instead of new/delete ?

Comment: So i dont understand the error, i clearly defined buffer in `double *buffer = (double *)malloc(len_arr * sizeof(double));` within the if condition, why it says not declared ?

Comment: i will try new/delete, thanks for your suggestion! im new to c++ so i am using outdated methods from outdated tutorials i guess